# Returning Stack Variables

Tags: c++, stack, return

I'm trying to figure out how to call a function that returns a stack-type variable. This is a very simple block of code I made to see if this approach works, but it didn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>

stack<int> ReturnStack(stack<int>);

int main () 
{
    stack<int> z;
    stack<int> x;
    z.push(1);
    z.push(2);
    z.push(3);
    x = ReturnStack(z); 
}

stack<int> ReturnStack(stack<int> z)
{
    return z;
}
```

It throws up a bunch of errors, and refuses to work. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make a successful call to something returning a stack? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what pass-by-value/call-by-value is? Go read about it.

Comment: Can you post this "bunch of errors" so we don't have to compile this ourselves? (do they complain about not finding `stack`? Write `std::stack` instead of `stack`).

Comment: Why are you including stdio.h and stdlib.h? Why doesn't main have a return statement (even if the compiler generates one automagically)?

Comment: *It throws up a bunch of errors* is hardly as useful as listing the first of the errors. An extra advantage of listing the error is that people can explain what each part of the message means, and that will help you understand other errors in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`stack` is in the `std` namespace. If (as a quick band aid, not a true fix) you put `using std::stack;` before the declaration of `ReturnStack`, it compiles without any problems.

Comment: @SantoshKantharaj remember to accept the answer which helped you most.

Comment: @oldrinb: I didn't see it while I was writing this, but R. Martinho Fernandes point the right answer in a comment a minute or so before I posted this, so he should really get credit for the right answer.